# return type []double issue in java

Tags: java, arrays

This code have something wrong, having error in return type.

```
    public static []double convertLatLong(String lat, String lng) {
        ........
     double latitude=....;
     double longitude=....;

     return (new []double{latitude,longitude});
     }
```

But it works fine with...

```
public static double[] convertLatLong(String lat, String lng) {
        ........
     double latitude=....;
     double longitude=....;

     return (new double[]{latitude,longitude});
     }
```

So, what is difference between them? 
While java supports declarations `data_type [] var_name` as well as `data_type var_name []`.

Comment: Maybe you should write `double[]` instead of `[]double`...

Comment: `[] data_type` is not valid in Java. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html It's either `dataType[] name` or `dataType name[]`. But I would highly recommend the first one.

Comment: sorry for my mistake,question is data_type [] var_name and data_type var_name []  are vaild in java.

Comment: What's your question? Just use `dataType[] varName`...

Comment: @satvindersingh: Please don't attempt to deface answers again, as per your rejected edits to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked: "So, what is difference between them? While java supports declarations data_type [] var_name as well as data_type var_name []."

Compare carefully:

> public static []double convertLatLong(String lat, String lng) // error

is to

> public static double[] convertLatLong(String lat, String lng) // correct

AS

> []data_type var_name // error

is to

> data_type[] var_name // correct

while

> data_type var_name[] // also valid

has nothing in common with either of the function declarations (egads @ Jon)

Does that help?

Answer (score 3):

(Quoting the question before it was edited...)

> while java supports declarations data_type [] as well as [] data_type.

No it doesn't. What it *does* support (horribly) is putting the `[]` *later* in some cases. For example, both of these are valid but nasty IMO:

```
double foo[]; // Ugly

// Completely insane
public double theGogglesTheyDoNothing()[] {
    return new double[10];
}
```

I've never seen the latter used in real code - it's utterly horrible. The first occasionally crops up, but is strongly discouraged.

But `[]double` is *never* valid as far as I'm aware.

The preferred form is just to put the square brackets directly after the type name, so your code would be:

```
public static double[] convertLatLong(String lat, String lng) {
    double latitude=....;
    double longitude=....;

    return new double[] { latitude, longitude };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
public static double[] convertLatLong(String lat, String lng) {
    double latitude = ...
    double longitude = ...;

    return new double[] { latitude, longitude };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The signature of the method should be either like this:

```
public static double[] convertLatLong(String lat, String lng)
```

or like this:

```
public static double convertLatLong(String lat, String lng)[]
```

---

Also, the return statement should be like this:

```
return new double[]{latitude, longitude};
```